# Square Peg Problem counterexample

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

[Inscribed square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem):

> Every continuous simple closed curve in the plane
>   contains four points that are the vertices of a
>   square.

I thinking about possibility of creating counter example to this. What if we create curve that can't have this property?

We can start from isosceles right-angled triangle $A$ because as far I know it can only have two squares in in it. Right now for this triangle conjecture hold but what happens when we alter locally this triangle a bit?

First observation is that 3 points of square determine position of 4th point, then we can create for set all possible $a$, $b$, $c$ points from triangle $A$ that create on they own new isosceles right-angled triangle $B_{a,b,c}$.
Now for each this triangle we can construct square that match 3 vertex of this triangle and that determine 4th $d_{a,b,c} = f(a,b,c)$ vertex ($a = f(a, b, d_{a,b,c})$ e.t.c.).

Now when we create set $C_{A}$ of this $d_{a,b,c}$ points and if it intersect with $A$ then this conjecture holds.

Another observation is if we alter some curve $E$ locally then set $C_{E}$ do not change in same local area because it depend on other parts of $E$ (one thing to check is how much other parts of $C_{E}$ change).

With this if we can made that all points of $C_{E}$ of some curve $E$ that intersect with $E$ are isolated from rest of $C_{E}$ then we can alter $E$ to new curve $E^\prime$ that avoid points of $C_{E}$ and $C_{E^\prime}$.

Now when we back to out triangle $A$, set $C_{A}$ consists of line segments that interact with $A$, this intersection AFAIK define two squares.
However some of this lines end on intersection points this allow us to change locally $A$ in that way that that $A^\prime$ it will not intersect with $C_{A}$ or $C_{A^\prime}$.

Do this logic have any apparent flaws? Right now I can easy "destroy" using this method two squares in that are inscribed on our triangle $A$ but I don't know yet if doing this I create new one in other place.

[image: triangle A]

Legend:

black - triangle $A$

green - two squares inscribed in $A$

red - set $C_{A}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After week of digging I verify that my approach will not work.
Primary reason is how set $C_{A}$ behave.

I write JavaScript code to approximate this set:

https://jsfiddle.net/5uazu2x2/ (need up to date bowers to work)

One observation I get is that $C_{A}$ will always split curve $A$ in separate parts. And if I not split then it overlap with $A$.
Some examples:

[image: triangle]
[image: another triangle]
[image: square]
[image: pentagon]
[image: flower]
[image]

Each place whenever red set $C_{A}$ intersect with set $A$ we have place where vertex of inscribed square lay (except for vertex of $A$ with sharp angles, like in triangles).

Another interesting thing I find is how we can construct $C_{A}$:

For each point $a$ from $A$ we create two new sets $R_{A,a}$ and $L_{A,a}$.

$R_{A,a}$ - This is set $A$ rotated by $\pi / 4$ and scaled up by $\sqrt{2}$ around point $a$

$L_{A,a}$ - This is set $A$ rotated by $-\pi / 4$ and scaled up by $\sqrt{2}$ around point $a$

Now intersection of $R_{A,a}$ and $L_{A,a}$ are points that belong to $C_{A}$:
[image]